# Azure web and worker role - 2x small instances or 1x medium?

Tags: performance, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

Which is better in terms of performance, 2 medium role instances or 4 small role instances?

What are the pro's and cons of each configuration?

Comment: What are you actually going to host in it ? Simple website anything more complex than that? Are you connecting to database ? or any storage for example ?

Comment: Its an asp.net web site talking to a sql azure db. It also uses Azure blob storage

Answer (score 2):

The only real way to know if you gain advantage of using larger instances is trying and measuring, not asking here. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn197896.aspx) has a table that says that a medium instance has everything twice as large as a small one. However in real life your mileage may vary and how this affects your application only you can measure.

Smaller roles have one important advantage - if instances fail separately you get smaller performance degradation. Supposing you know about "guaranteed uptime" requirement of having at least two instances, you have to choose between two medium and four small instances. If one small instance fails you lose 1/4 of your performance, but if one medium instance fails you lose half of performance.

Instances will fail if for example you have an unhandled exception inside `Run()` of your role entry point descendant and sometimes something just goes wrong big time and your code can't handle this and it'd better just restart. Not that you should deliberately target for such failures but you should expect them and take measures to minimize impact to your application.

So the bottom line is - it's impossible to say which gets better performance, but uptime implications are just as important and they are clearly in favor of smaller instances.

Answer (score 2):

Good points by @sharptooth. One more thing to consider: When scaling *in*, the fewest number of instances is *one*, not *zero*. So, say you have a worker role that does some nightly task for an hour, and it requires either 2 Medium or 4 Small instances to get the job done in that timeframe. When the work is done, you may want to save costs by scaling to one instance and let it run as one instance for 23 hours until the next nightly job. With a single Small instance, you'll burn 23 core-hours, and with a single Medium instance, you'll burn 46 core-hours. This thinking also applies to your Web role, but probably more-so since you will probably have minimum two instances to make sure you have uptime SLA (it may not be as important for you to have SLA on your worker if, say, your end user never interacts with it and it's just for utility purposes).

My general rule of thumb when sizing: Pick the smallest VM size that can properly do the work, and then scale out/in as needed. Your choice will primarily be driven by CPU, RAM, and network bandwidth needs (and don't forget you need network when moving data between Compute and Storage).

Answer (score 1):

For a start, you won't get the guaranteed uptime of 99% unless you have at least 2 <del>roles</del> role instances, this allows one to die and be restarted while the other one takes the burden. Otherwise, it is a case of how much you want to pay and what specs you get on each. It has not caused me any hassle having more than one <del>role</del> role instance, Azure hides the difficult stuff.

Answer (score 0):

One other point maybe worth a mention if you use four small roles you would be able to run two in one datacenter and two in another datacenter and use traffic manager to route people at least which is closer. This might give you some performance gains.

Two mediums will give you more options to store stuff in cache at compute level and thus more in cache rather than coming off SQL Azure it is going to be faster.

Ideally you have to follow @sharptooth and measure and test. This is all very subjective and I second David also you want to start as small as possible and scale outwards. We run this way, you really want to think about designing your app around a more sharding aspect as this fits azure model better than working in traditional sense of just getting a bigger box to run everything on, at some point you run out into limits thinking in the bigger box process, ie.Like SQL Azure Connection limits.

Using technologies like Jmeter is your friend here and should give you some tools to test your app.

http://jmeter.apache.org/